# Why every polynomial over the algebraic numbers $F$ splits over $F$?

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

I read that if $F$ is the field of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$, then every polynomial in $F[x]$ splits over $F$. That's awesome! Nevertheless, I don't fully understand why it is true. Can you throw some ideas about why this is true?

Comment: Isn't that more or less the definition of [algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number)?

Comment: More or less, but not quite. This is saying that every polynomial in $F[X]$ factors over $F$.

Comment: The question is why the field of algebraic numbers is algebraically closed.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading that every polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ splits over $F$ ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, you should add that it is the field of all algebraic numbers, in case of misread, thanks.

Comment: This is the transitivity of algebraic extension. If $L$ is an algebraic extension of $K$ and $K$ is an algebraic extension of $F$ then $L$ is also an algebraic extension of $F$. Here we use $F = \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 8):

The fact you mention is that the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of algebraic numbers is **algebraically closed**.  This is true because it is the **algebraic closure** of the field $\mathbb{Q}$ inside the larger algebraically closed field $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., the set of all complex numbers which satisfy some nonzero polynomial equation with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients.

Notwithstanding the terminology, that the algebraic closure of a field in an algebraically closed field is algebraically closed requires (nontrivial) proof!  See for instance $\S 4$ of [my notes on field theory](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf), especially Proposition 17 and Corollary 18.

Answer (score 3):

Consider some polynomial $$x^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i x^i,$$ where the $c_i$ are algebraic numbers. Thus for each $i$ we have a similar identity $$c_i^{n_i} = \sum_{j=0}^{n_i-1} d_{i,j} c_i^j,$$ where this time the $d_{i,j}$ are rationals.

Suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of the original polynomial. By using the above identities, every power of $\alpha$ can be expressed as a linear combination *with rational coefficients* of terms of the form $$\alpha^m c_0^{m_0} \cdots c_{n-1}^{m_{n-1}},$$ where $$0 \leq m < n \text{ and } 0 \leq m_i < n_i.$$ Putting all these $N = nn_0\cdots n_{n-1}$ elements into a vector $v$, we get that there are *rational* vectors $u_k$ such that $$\alpha^k = \langle u_k,v \rangle.$$ Among the first $N+1$ vectors $u_k$ there must be some non-trivial *rational* linear combination that vanishes: $$\sum_{k=0}^N t_k u_k = 0.$$ Therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^N t_k \alpha^k = 0,$$ and so $\alpha$ is also algebraic.

This proof is taken from [these lecture notes](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec09.pdf), but it's pretty standard.